# For which $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ is $\sin \circ P$ a periodic function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

For what $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is the function $\sin(p(x))$ periodic?

It seems obvious to me that all linear polynomials satisfy the condition, but I can not prove it and I do not know what other functions can satisfy it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Maths Stack Exchange. Could you show us your thoughts about the question?

Comment: it seems obvious to me that all linear polynomials satisfy the condition, but I can not prove it and do not know what other functions can satisfy it

Comment: @Luk17 *why* is it obvious. Have you tried using $p(x)=x^2$ as an experiment? What about $p(x)=\sin(x)$?

Comment: for linear and periodic $p(x)$

Comment: I tried using $p(x)=x^2$ and it isn't periodic.

Comment: The fact is that it is necessary to find all $p(x)$ for which $sin(p(x))$ is periodic and prove that the ones found are all.

Answer (score 9):

The key idea is the following :

> Let $f \, : \, \mathbb{R} \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function with period $T$.
>
> If $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f'$ is periodic with period $T$.

If $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \; f(t) = \sin\big( P(t) \big)$ with $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \; f'(t) = P'(t) \cos\big( P(t) \big). $$

Therefore, $f'$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $P'$ is. This implies that $\deg(P) \leq 1$.

Conversely, if $\deg(P) \leq 1$, $P'$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.